# php smarty multiple parameters

Tags: php, smarty

I am iterating an object and all is going well until I deal with multiple parameters. How do I output this properly in smarty?

```
 <td id="dc_creator">
      Posted by: " . {$entry.children('dc', true).creator} 
 </td>
```

Thank you for your time. I have also tried this with no luck:

```
 <td id="dc_creator">
      Posted by: " . {$entry|children:'dc':true|creator}
 </td>
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is in $entry. Your first example looks like it's an object with a `children` function that returns an associative array that can contain a `creator` element, but you need to provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

If `$entry` is an object you should use:

```
<td id="dc_creator">
      Posted by: " . {$entry->children('dc', true)->creator} 
</td>
```

or

```
<td id="dc_creator">
      Posted by: " . {$entry->children('dc', true).creator} 
</td>
```

If it doesn't work please provide sample entry data to help you